# is there a way to launch google device inspect on cordova run app on device function

Tags: android, ios, cordova, google-chrome, android-webview

I am debugging app with cordova and I have always wondered if there was a way to launch googles device inspect as soon as the app starts running on the device.

[image: Google Device Inspect]

This screen is familier to most but just wondering if there is a more efficient way of opening the inspect for the web-view without having to wait for app to install then launching the inspector and lastly hitting refresh to get the get the network information.

So some call back like:

> cordova run --device OS --launch device-inspect

Answer (score 1):

[GapDebug](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/), which seems to be merely a wrapper around chrome inspect, promises a feature like this:

> GapDebug detects an app termination and restart, such as during an app update, and automatically reconnects the app with the previous debug session. Quickly get back to debugging when the app closes on your device.

Taken from their [features site](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/features/)...

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there isn't.

If you make changes to the code you have to compile and install the app on your device or else you won't have the most recent build.

And if I'm not mistaken the way "Inspect" works is by attaching to a running process and you can only start to "listen" after the process has already been created.

Or as [@Phonolog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5730444/phonolog) sugested, use another debugger